# How can I find out where `apt install` has installed the program (and when)?

Tags: apt, software-installation

If `apt install` reports a program has been installed, how can I find out where `apt install` has installed the program? Note that `which` and `whereis` don't necessarily just report that information. Does `apt` have its own command for that?   Thanks.

Also can I find out when `apt install` last installed a program? Is it just by looking at the mtime of the executable file? Does `apt` provide some way to do that?

For example:

```
$ sudo apt install wine-stable
[sudo] password for t: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
wine-stable is already the newest version (3.0.1~bionic).
wine-stable set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

Comment: `dpkg -L wine-stable` should show you where *all* the package's files are installed

Comment: `apt` is a front-end for `dpkg`. `dpkg` maintains a log at `/var/log/dpkg.log`.

Comment: @Tim - Here is an overview of apt-commands concerning packages and to get infos about packages ... https://www.tecmint.com/useful-basic-commands-of-apt-get-and-apt-cache-for-package-management/ and here is too something: http://newbiedoc.sourceforge.net/tutorials/apt-get-intro/info.html.en

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you can accomplish this, my common fallback (because its simple) is

`apt-file show chromium-browser`

You'll have to add `apt-file` if you choose this method.

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   apt-file show chromium-browser
chromium-browser: /etc/chromium-browser/customizations/00-example
chromium-browser: /etc/chromium-browser/default
chromium-browser: /etc/default/chromium-browser
chromium-browser: /usr/bin/chromium-browser
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/MEIPreload/manifest.json
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/MEIPreload/preloaded_data.pb
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/WidevineCdm/manifest.json
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome-sandbox
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome_100_percent.pak
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome_200_percent.pak
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/headless_lib.pak
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/icudtl.dat
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/keyboard_resources.pak
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/locales/en-US.pak
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/mus_app_resources_100.pak
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/mus_app_resources_200.pak
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/mus_app_resources_strings.pak
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/natives_blob.bin
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/resources.pak
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/snapshot_blob.bin
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/swiftshader/libEGL.so
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/transport_security_state_generator
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/v8_context_snapshot.bin
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/views_mus_resources.pak
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/xdg-mime
chromium-browser: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/xdg-settings
chromium-browser: /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
chromium-browser: /usr/share/apport/package-hooks/chromium-browser.py
chromium-browser: /usr/share/doc/chromium-browser/README.source
chromium-browser: /usr/share/doc/chromium-browser/changelog.Debian.gz
chromium-browser: /usr/share/doc/chromium-browser/copyright
chromium-browser: /usr/share/doc/chromium-browser/copyright.problems.gz
chromium-browser: /usr/share/gnome-control-center/default-apps/chromium-browser.xml
chromium-browser: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/chromium-browser.png
chromium-browser: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/chromium-browser.png
chromium-browser: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/chromium-browser.png
chromium-browser: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/chromium-browser.png
chromium-browser: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/chromium-browser.png
chromium-browser: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/chromium-browser.png
chromium-browser: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/chromium-browser.svg
chromium-browser: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/chromium-browser
chromium-browser: /usr/share/man/man1/chromium-browser.1.gz
chromium-browser: /usr/share/pixmaps/chromium-browser.png
```

fyi: *the extra spaces before the command (after my prompt) were so the command didn't show in my `history`. this of course doesn't work if you're remote (eg. you ssh'd into your box), or its been secured to prevent this.*

If its a box you want to keep light though, I'd recommend `dpkg -L` as @steeldriver suggested (it is installed by default), and is likely the tool used by apt-show anyway :)

As for when, you could use something like

`zcat /var/log/apt/hist* |grep chromium-browser -B 2 -A 2`

which searches my logs for "chromium-browser"; displaying that line (*plus 2 lines before & after it to ensure I see the date/time*). This is what @AlexP referred to in his comment. An example of the output for my box included

```
Start-Date: 2017-11-16  13:53:13
Commandline: apt install glances htop iftop cowsay fortune figlet nfs-common chromium-browser
Requested-By: guiverc (1000)
Install: python-six:amd64 (1.10.0-4, automatic), ttf-bitstream-vera:amd64 (1.10-8, automatic), fortune-mod:amd64 (1:1.99.1-7), fonts-lyx:amd64 (2.2.3-1, automatic), python3-pystache:amd64 (0.5.4-6, automatic), liblapack3:amd64 (3.7.1-3ubuntu2, automatic), javascript-common:amd64 (11, automatic), python3-dateutil:amd64 (2.6.0-1, automatic), iftop:amd64 (1.0~pre4-4), figlet:amd64 (2.2.5-3), blt:amd64 (2.5.3+dfsg-3, automatic), python2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.14-2ubuntu2, automatic), python2.7:amd64 (2.7.14-2ubuntu2, automatic), python3-netifaces:amd64 (0.10.4-0.1build4, automatic), libjs-jquery:amd64 (3.1.1-2, automatic), python-matplotlib-data:amd64 (2.0.0+dfsg1-2ubuntu3, automatic), python3-matplotlib:amd64 (2.0.0+dfsg1-2ubuntu3, automatic), fortunes-min:amd64 (1:1.99.1-7, automatic), python3-psutil:amd64 (5.0.1-1build2, automatic), libquadmath0:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3, automatic), python3-numpy:amd64 (1:1.12.1-3.1ubuntu4, automatic), python:amd64 (2.7.14-2ubuntu1, automatic), python3-cycler:amd64 (0.10.0-1, automatic), librecode0:amd64 (3.6-23, automatic), htop:amd64 (2.0.2-1), python3-pyparsing:amd64 (2.1.10+dfsg1-1, automatic), python3-docker:amd64 (1.9.0-1, automatic), libpython-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.14-2ubuntu1, automatic), hddtemp:amd64 (0.3-beta15-52, automatic), chromium-browser:amd64 (62.0.3202.89-0ubuntu0.17.10.1386), libgfortran4:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3, automatic), python3-pysnmp4:amd64 (4.3.2-2, automatic), libtirpc1:amd64 (0.2.5-1.2, automatic), libjs-jquery-ui:amd64 (1.12.1+dfsg-5, automatic), tk8.6-blt2.5:amd64 (2.5.3+dfsg-3, automatic), glances:amd64 (2.10-2), python3-tk:amd64 (3.6.3-0ubuntu1, automatic), python3-tz:amd64 (2017.2-2, automatic), lm-sensors:amd64 (1:3.4.0-4, automatic), python3-influxdb:amd64 (4.1.1-1, automatic), libblas3:amd64 (3.7.1-3ubuntu2, automatic), chromium-browser-l10n:amd64 (62.0.3202.89-0ubuntu0.17.10.1386, automatic), cowsay:amd64 (3.03+dfsg2-3), python3-websocket:amd64 (0.44.0-0ubuntu2, automatic), rpcbind:amd64 (0.2.3-0.6, automatic), python-minimal:amd64 (2.7.14-2ubuntu1, automatic), python3-bottle:amd64 (0.12.13-1, automatic), nfs-common:amd64 (1:1.3.4-2.1ubuntu2), libjs-angularjs:amd64 (1.5.10-1, automatic), libjs-lodash:amd64 (4.17.4+dfsg-1, automatic), python3-pyasn1:amd64 (0.1.9-2, automatic), libnfsidmap2:amd64 (0.25-5.1, automatic), cowsay-off:amd64 (3.03+dfsg2-3, automatic)
End-Date: 2017-11-16  13:54:13
```